# openserver очень медленно выполняется функция is_dir

Tags: php, производительность, openserver

Есть сайт (даже несколько сайтов, на разных cms). На хостинге они работают быстро, на ноуте - медленно... для примера, сайт, который я профилировал, на сервере запускается до 3-6сек, на ноуте больше 20сек...

Профилирование на ноуте с помощью xhprof показало, что на выполнение функции is_dir потрачено около 13 сек (где-то 250microsec на 1 выполнение, это дольше чем многие запросы к базе данных при загрузки этой же страницы) и 2 сек на opendir( где-то 400microsec на операцию). На все запросы к базе данных 0,3сек (т.е. более-менее)

На ноуте проц i7, 8gb ОЗУ, жесткий ST1000LM014-SSHD-8GB, windows 10, Openserver. Тестировал на php 5.4 (но ситуация одинаковая на разных версиях)

Как можно ускорить работу openserver и уменьшить время загрузки сайтов на локалке?

Comment: 1/4 миллисекунды - это прямо очень хорошо для I/O с участием обычного жесткого диска. Я думаю, причина все-таки в том, что заставляет is_dir вызываться ~60000 раз на один запрос, нежели в самой скорости is_dir.

Comment: уменьшить количество запросов не получится, так как это CMS, к тому же результаты этой функции кешируются, т.е. реальное выполнение этих функций значительно больше... тем более я не думаю, что сервера имеют винчестеры, которые работают более чем в 10 раз быстрее... (на тестовом хостинге  тарифный план не ssd). для чистоты эксперимента, я кэш на хостинге отключил

Comment: возражу - это как раз таки время ответа файловой системы существенно уменьшить не получится ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (а вот повлиять на количество вызовов у вас больше шансов)

Comment: @etki, получится, причём просто: купить ssd :D

Comment: @Qwertiy sad but https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832

Comment: большое спасибо. оказалось, что тема на локалхосте  работала в dev режиме и для детальной отладки ела очень много ресурсов (как раз и использовала  is_dir ). Перевел в продакшн - всё стало нормально

Comment: @Alex, ответы в ответы?

Comment: если бы @etki оформил свой коммент в виде ответа, с допиской, что нужно проверить в каком режиме работает сайт - я бы принял этот ответ...